# how to export limited number of rows from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

Our production DB is very big. I would like to export just a few thousands of record from it preferably with pg:pull...

Is there a way to accomplish that?
Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, but there's no way to limit rows with `pg:pull`. However there's another way to make a backup of DB. Here's a link to [Heroku Import/Export Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export). You can use `pgbackups` tool to create a backup. After that, you can simply download it from Heroku.

Another way could be using `pg_dump` tool (PostgreSQL tool for creating DB dumps), but, as far as I know, it has no way of limiting number of records. However **you can dump a table structure without records** with `pg_dump`, and then fill it by yourself or by using custom script. Also, you can try and save a limited number of records to file using [SQL COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).